# Find the odd ones out!

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, odd-one-out

Find the odd ones out! Each section will have 1 part that is the odd one out.

**1.**

> Computer
>    Chancellor
>    Conference
>    Coincide
>    Curriculum
>    Continue
>    Champion
>    Customer

**2.**

> [image]

**3**

> Uryc
>    Rvtug Qnlf n Jrrx
>    Qba'g Fgbc Oryvriva
>    Urer Pbzrf gur Fha
>    Url Whqr

**4**

> [image]

**5**

> Zpv ibwf gpvoe ju
>    V or DhnaghzGjvaxvr
>    Lbh ner ernqvat guvf
>    Fbzr jbeqf
>    Chmmyrf ner sha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. @Riley

> Curriculum is the only word without the letter 'o'.

2. @WELZ, @QuantumTwinkie

> Potatoes are the only one not related to travel. -WELZ 
>
>  Radar, Kayak, Race car are spelled the same backwards, but not potato -QuantumTwinkie.

3. @WELZ, @Riley

> rot13 gives
>
>  Help
>  Eight Days a Week
>  Don't Stop Believin
>  Here Comes the Sun
>  Hey Jude
>
>  where "Don't Stop Believin" is the only song not by the Beatles.

4. @Riley

> "Earth" is the odd one out because the other words "purple", "orange", "ninja", "iron", and "music" arguably have no rhymes.

5. @Riley

> Each line is rot13 except the first, which is rot25. The decoded lines are:
>
>  *You have found it*
>  I be QuantumTwinkie
>  You are reading this
>  Some words
>  Puzzles are fun

Answer (score 2):

Partial Answer:

The differences:

> 1: Curriculum
> 2: Potatoes
> 3: Qba'g Fgbc Oryvriva (Don't Stop Believin)
> 4: 
> 5: Zpv ibwf gpvoe ju (rot25 to You have found it)

---

1:

> Curriculum doesn't have an O (all the other ones do)

2:

> Potatoes (The other 3 somehow relate to travel)

3:

> Rot13'd truns up:
>  
>  Help
>  
> Eight Days a Week
> Don't Stop Believin
> Here Comes the Sun
> Hey Jude
>
> As [Riley mentioned](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64043/find-the-odd-ones-out/64044#comment194461_64044):
> All the songs are by the Beatles, except Don't Stop Believin (Journey)

4:

> Unknown for now

5: (From [Riley's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/64045/45083))

> First line: `Mci vojs tcibr wh`
>  
>  rot25 is: "`You have found it`"
>  
>  rest are rot13

Comment: For number 3: rot13(Qba'g fgbc oryvrivat vf gur bayl bar abg ol gur Orngyrf.)

Comment: I got the same thing for #1 first.

Comment: @Riley got 1 first.

Comment: If everything's correct, I'll make a community wiki answer if that's okay.

Comment: So, all are solved but I had the reason for number 2 because all of the other words were the same backwards and forwards (radar,kayak, race car)

Answer (score 2):

Partial Answer

Guess on 1.

> Curriculum is the only word not containing the letter "o".

4.

> It could be "earth" as the other words "orange", "purple", "ninja", "iron", and "music" arguably have no rhymes.

5.

> Applying rot13 to all of the lines we get
>
> ```
> Mci vojs tcibr wh
> I be QuantumTwinkie
> You are reading this
> Some words
> Puzzles are fun
> ```
>
> So the first line is clearly the odd one out. Also, it is a ROT cipher, just not ROT13. It encodes "You have found it"